# I am trying to use dynamic memory to allocate memory for two arrays using structs

Tags: c

The functions work perfectly fine separately(ie when on of them is commented the other works fine). However, when I call both sets of functions it gives me an error saying:

kwoc3(7542,0x113609d40) malloc: *** error for object 0x7ffee5e8ea18: pointer being realloc'd was not allocated
kwoc3(7542,0x113609d40) malloc: *** set a breakpoint in malloc_error_break to debug
Abort trap: 6

Here is my code:

```
#include <assert.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include "emalloc.h"
#include "listy.h"

#define MAX_LINE_LEN 100
#define MAX_WORD_LEN 40

typedef struct Lines_and_Words Lines_and_Words;
struct Lines_and_Words{
    char array_lines[MAX_LINE_LEN];
};

struct Ntab{
    Lines_and_Words *lines;
    int max_elements;
    int index;
};

enum{
    NINIT = 8,
    NGROW = 2
};

void command_line_input(int argc, char *argv[], char **input_file, char **exp_filename);
void read_file_in_array(char *filename, struct Ntab *ntab);
int add_line(char *line, struct Ntab *ntab);
void store_words(struct Ntab *ntab, node_t **words, int *word_counter);

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    char *filename = NULL;
    struct Ntab ntab_lines;
    node_t *words = NULL;
    int word_counter = 0;

    char *exp_filename = NULL;
    struct Ntab ntab_exp_lines;
    node_t *exp_words = NULL;
    int exp_word_counter = 0;

    command_line_input(argc, argv, &filename, &exp_filename);

    read_file_in_array(filename, &ntab_lines);
    store_words(&ntab_lines, &words, &word_counter);

    read_file_in_array(exp_filename, &ntab_exp_lines);
    store_words(&ntab_exp_lines, &exp_words, &exp_word_counter);

#ifdef DEBUG
    _demo();
#endif

    exit(0);
}

void command_line_input(int argc, char *argv[], char **input_file, char **exp_file){
    if (argc == 2){
        *input_file = argv[1];
        *exp_file = NULL;
    }else if(argc == 4){
        if(strcmp(argv[2],"-e") == 0){
            *exp_file = argv[3];
            *input_file = argv[1];
        }else if(strcmp(argv[1], "-e") == 0){
            *exp_file = argv[2];
            *input_file = argv[3];
        }
    }else if(argc == 1 || argc == 3){
        printf("Need more arguments");
        exit(1);
    }
}

void read_file_in_array(char *filename, struct Ntab *ntab){
    FILE *fptr;
    char *line = NULL;
    size_t len = 0;
    ssize_t read;

    fptr = fopen(filename, "r");
    while((read = getline(&line, &len, fptr)) != -1){
        add_line(line, ntab);
    }
}

int add_line(char *line, struct Ntab *ntab){
    Lines_and_Words *lp;

    if (ntab->lines == NULL){
        ntab->lines = (Lines_and_Words *)malloc(NINIT * sizeof(Lines_and_Words));
        if (ntab->lines == NULL){
            return -1;
        }
        ntab->max_elements = NINIT;
        ntab->index = 0;
    }else if(ntab->index >= ntab->max_elements){
        lp = (Lines_and_Words *) realloc(ntab->lines, (NGROW * ntab->max_elements) * sizeof(Lines_and_Words));
        if (lp == NULL){
            return -1;
        }
        ntab->max_elements *= NGROW;
        ntab->lines = lp;
    }
    strncpy(ntab->lines[ntab->index].array_lines, line, MAX_LINE_LEN);
    return ntab->index++;
}

void store_words(struct Ntab *ntab, node_t **words, int *word_counter){
    int buff_line_num = 0;
    char buffer[MAX_LINE_LEN];
    const char delim[] = " \n";
    char *token;

    for (int i = 0; i<ntab->index; i++){
        strncpy(buffer, ntab->lines[i].array_lines, MAX_LINE_LEN);
        token = strtok(buffer, delim);
        while (token != NULL){
            node_t *new_p = new_node(token);
            *words = add_end(*words, new_p);
            *word_counter = *word_counter + 1;

            token = strtok(NULL, delim);
        }
        buff_line_num++;
    }
}
```

I don't know how to fix this. Any comments would be helpful.

Comment: <O/T> What if your program doesn't get 1, 2, 3, or 4 arguments?

Comment: The variable `struct Ntab ntab_lines;` in `main` has not been initialised. So if `ntab->lines` is not `NULL` you can't assume that it can be reallocated. In C you must explicitly initialise local variables.

Comment: @WeatherVane that worked, thanks!